# Блокирующие сессии в Oracle

Tags: oracle

В `PL/SQL developer` на вкладке `Tools > Sessions`, есть сессии к различным схемам БД `Oracle`. Подскажите пожалуйста как определить сессию, которая зависла? В каких полях видны статусы? Я не знаток oracle, поэтому заранее извиняюсь, за может быть глупый вопрос.

Можно было бы ссылку еще на ресурс, где описано это.

Answer (score 1):

По дереву блокирующих сессий. Верхушка - проблемная сессия

```
select lpad('*', level, '*') lvl, level, s.* 
from v$session s
where not (level = 1 and connect_by_isleaf = 1)
start with blocking_session is null
connect by blocking_session = prior sid
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую запрос